# How to detect collisions between a point and a tube in space?

Tags: collision-detection, 3d

Alright, so I am wondering in general if given a tube that follows a curve in space whether or not there is a way to detect if a point is within the tube? I am assuming that a curve is a continuous function taking a single value and returning a point. I would assume this is done via a comparison with the shortest distance to the curve. Is there a formula that works for all curves? I looked around and found that most things rely upon calculus and derivatives of the curves. Preferably, it would work in the general case without having to rely upon calculus.

Comment: The edits being proposed to this question are _entirely reasonable_; I see no evidence that they are "removing context," and attempts to roll them back seem like overreactions. That said, the edits do not seem significant enough to enforce, so I don't see a reason to enforce them when the OP clearly, for whatever reason, does not want them. Please don't escalate this rollback war further. If you feel that the question is too broad, or otherwise poor or inappropriate fashion, use your votes to express that. If you wish to discuss the issue further, please do so in meta or chat.

Answer (score 0):

Get a parametric definition for the curve, using that you can have x, y, and z in function of the parameter. Then you define the distance from the point a, b, b to a point x, y, z on the curve by using Euclidean distance.

Now, you have a function that gives you the distance to your point from the parameters. (x, y, z) should have been gone, because you replace them by their parametric functions.

Use second derivate method to find at what value of the parameter you have the minimum value for the distance.

Evaluate the parametric functions for x, y and z with the found parameter value, and there you have point on the curve that is closest to the point you have.

You can build you collision detection with that and the radius of the tube.

---

Without knowing the curve, and without using calculus, you would have to go for numeric methods. I'm unsure what would be appropiate for 3D... yet, I can tell you that the implementation with calculus is more efficient, because using numeric mehtods means iterations.

---

Addendum: Perhaps the problem is doing the derivation itself. In that case you can do [Numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) and then [Root Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find an inflection points of the distance equation.

It should be noted that without the second derivate method you can't tell if what you found is a minimun or a maximun. Also, note that numeric methods are prone to result in local optimizations... so you may end up with a local minimun or maximun instead of the global minimun you want.

So, you could try finding the root using AI. Something like [Stochastic hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_hill_climbing) or [Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) would work. Yet, on this point we are no longer talking about finding the distance, but about finding something close enough, where "enough" depends on how much time you have to search for it.

Are you sure calculus is the harder option here?

Comment: So there isn't a formula that works without calculus?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck having no idea of what the curve is... no, I'm sure there are algorithms (not formulas) that can handle an arbitrary curve, yet I can't think of one worth advising.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is approximate your curve with straight, tubular segments. How many points along the curve you sample to do this, and thus how many segments you end up with, is your choice.

Then for each straight, tubular segment approximating your curve:

- Get tube's backbone axis in its own local space, defined as a `yz` position and a set of extents in `x` (`min, max`), and its 3x3 world space orientation matrix.
- Transform the point from world space into the cylinder's/tube's space (using inverse 3x3 orientation matrix)
- Check the point falls within the `x` extents AND
- Check the point falls within some radius `r` of the `yz` axis position, using Pythagoras.

The only thing you would still need to attend to here, is the "ball-joint" corners between each tubular segment representing the curve. There you would need to add an extra step:

- Check the point falls within a spherical radius of the end point (`x max`) of every segment except the last segment (as this gives you every interstitial).

If it falls into either the the tube/cylinder OR the sphere, it is considered "inside" this segment. If it falls into any of the segments, then it is of course considered "inside" the tubular curve as a whole.

The good news is that unless you are raytracing, you will have a mesh constructed using essentially the same parameters. So this will give you accurate collision detection against the edges of the tube.